# developing simple functions

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define-struct animal (name species age breakfasthour dinnerhour))
(define-struct attendant (name a1 a2 a3))


(define gorilla (make-animal "Koko" "Gorilla" 4 "8" "10"))
(define bat (make-animal "Bruce" "Bat" 1 "23" "5"))
(define mandrill (make-animal "Manny" "Mandrill" 5 "8" "7"))
(define crocodile (make-animal "Swampy" "Crocodile" 1 "10" "8"))
(define ocelot (make-animal "Ozzy" "Ocelot" 7 "7" "17"))
(define capybara (make-animal "Capy" "Capybara" 4 "6" "8"))
(define potto (make-animal "Spot" "Potto" 2 "2" "6"))
(define tapir (make-animal "Stripey" "Tapir" 3 "10" "6"))
(define vulture (make-animal "Beaky" "Vulture" 10 "9" "6"))


(define attendant1 (make-attendant "Dave" gorilla bat mandrill))
(define attendant2 (make-attendant "John" crocodile ocelot capybara))
(define attendant3 (make-attendant "Joe" potto tapir vulture))
```

I need a function that takes an animal and returns whether its mealtime, if i take  gorilla, then dinner time would be at 10. This is what I've done. ignore the quotes on the numbers above.

```
(define (meal-time? e1 e2)
  (string=? (animal-species e1)
            (animal-dinnerhour e2)))
```

it runs, but wnt give me an output. any reason why it wont give me an output?

edit- `(meal-time? gorilla 10)`tells me it expects an animal, but given 10.

Comment: Can you show us how and where you call the function? Do you call it from the REPL or in a file?

Comment: the print loop. i type in for example (meal-time? gorilla 10) to find out whether its dinner time or not. it should give me yes, but it tells me it expects an animal, but given 10.

Comment: The next time you ask a question, you should include any error messages you're getting in the question. That's important information.

Answer (score 2):

Your `meal-time?` function takes two animals as arguments (because you use `animal-` accessor functions on both arguments), but you call it with an animal and a number. So you get an error message telling you that the second argument should be an animal.

If you call your function with two animals as arguments, you'll get no error any more. You'll get `#f`. What your function does is: it checks whether the species of the first animal is equal to the the dinner hour of the second animal. Since there is no species whose name is a number, that will never be true.

Comment: then how would I get it to take an animal and a number and give me a boolean? why won't animal-dinnerhour take in a number? it is part of the struct. we went over this in class.  this is so confusing.

Comment: @KevinR `animal-dinnerhour` takes an animal and returns its `dinnerhour`. What would you expect that function to do when applied to a number?

Comment: @KevinR. If by "ask me for an animal" you mean "Produce an error message that tells me to apply the function to an animal rather than a number", then yes, that's exactly what it's doing. But unless I misunderstood something, that behaviour surprised you, so you must have expected something different. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: No, that's what I meant. would i have to create a different struct so it can take in an animal and number and give me a boolean?

Comment: @KevinR. No, you don't need a second struct. You need to rewrite your function, so that it doesn't call `animal-` functions on its second argument. You should also rethink the logic of your function as it currently does not make any sense. You also need to consider that currently the animals' dinner hours are strings and the argument you're trying to pass to `meal-time?` is a number.